# Angular Live Development Server api requests not found

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core, angular-template

really confused about this and don't know where to start.

Basically i have generated a new angular project with the "dotnet new angular" command.

Im using a fresh machine, node, npm etc etc are all up to date.

My issue is this template just does not work out of the box. When i run the application, all of the frontend will load however, any requests to the api's etc will 404 stating that it cannot find the url.

Message in Chrome console: "Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment..."

My application runs on a different port everytime I execute the "dotnet run" command. Is this supposed to be the case ? Whichever port is generated, this will be the problematic one.

I have to manually change to port 5001 for anything to function correctly (although this comes with annoying security prompts.)

I am using visual studio code for this project. The funny thing is, if i run this project via visual studio (not code) i get a consistent static port number that will function as intended (this also comes with annoying security prompts) so i have to assume its this random port number that vscode is generating ?

Im honestly not to familiar with this so I could be way off admittedly. Any help or advice would be appreaciated. I'd post code snippets if I knew where to start.

PS, I know that I can of course just not run it with VSCode and just stick to Visual Studio. I'd rather understand the issue than ignore it though.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: What commands are you using? Also what do you mean "any requests to the api's etc will 404"?

Comment: Hi, im just using the "dotnet new angular" command to generate the project using the terminal in VS Code. From there I use "dotnet run". In the terminal I will get 3 messages: Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000 and Angular Live Development server listsening on localhost.... This last one changes port number everytime i use the dotnet run command. If i try to access my api on this port i will get a 404 "not found" response in Google Chrome console

Comment: That's because your .NET API is running on localhost:5001, the other port is for `@angular/cli`

Comment: Ah ok, I think I understand. At least enough to research a little further anyway. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: So for example in the template, you could call the `WeatherForecasts` action on the api with `https://localhost:5001/api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts`